# prove that $\forall k\geqslant1\land k\in\mathbb{Z}.\nexists q\in\mathbb{Z}.q^{2}=(k-i)(k+i)$

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, gaussian-integers

prove that $\forall k\geqslant1\land k\in\mathbb{Z}.\nexists q\in\mathbb{Z}.q^{2}=(k-i)(k+i)$.
My try: use gaussian integer to claim that we have ufd. the problem, is that k might not be irreducible in gaussian primes.
Edit: without using that non zero squares cannot differ by 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Two nonzero perfect squares in $\Bbb{Z}$ cannot differ by $1$.

Comment: this is what I try to prove with the gauss decomposition.

Comment: Why would you do that? The equation is equivalent to
$$(q-k)(q+k)=1.$$

Comment: can you prove it, without using this claim? Thanks